# Work out conditional expectation from a joint probability table

Tags: statistics

Say from a table of joint probabilities, of RV A and B:

```
    b_1 b_2 
a_1 0.1 0.2
a_2 0.5 0.2
```

In general, if say $a_1 < b_1 < b_2 < a_2$

And you want to work out some expected conditional probability with some variation of $A$ say $A = cA$, eg $E[cA|A<B]$.

My intuition says, in this case:

$P(A<B) = P(A=a_1$ and  $B=b_1)$ so;

$(cA)*(P(A=a_1$ AND $B=b_1)/P(B=b_1)=ca_1 * (0.1/0.6)$

This looks correct to me. But on occasion I get questions like this wrong. I struggle to see where I go wrong with my intuition. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that condition $A<B$ actually "forces" $A$ to take value $a_1$ so that:
$$\mathsf{E}\left[cA\mid A<B\right]=ca_{1}$$

Worked out in more steps:
$$\begin{aligned}\mathsf{E}\left[cA\mid A<B\right] & =ca_{1}\mathsf{P}\left(A=a_{1}\mid A<B\right)+ca_{2}\mathsf{P}\left(A=a_{2}\mid A<B\right)\\
 & =c\mathsf{P}\left(A<B\right)^{-1}\left[a_{1}\mathsf{P}\left(A=a_{1}\wedge A<B\right)+a_{2}\mathsf{P}\left(A=a_{2}\wedge A<B\right)\right]\\
 & =c\mathsf{P}\left(A<B\right)^{-1}\left[a_{1}\mathsf{P}\left(A=a_{1}\wedge a_{1}<B\right)+a_{2}\mathsf{P}\left(A=a_{2}\wedge a_{2}<B\right)\right]\\
 & =c0.3^{-1}\left[a_{1}\cdot0.3+a_{2}\cdot0\right]\\
 & =ca_{1}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Awesome thanks. And so this argument would hold true for other variations, ie $E[cA^n + d|A<B] = ca_1 ^n + d$ etc.

Comment: Yes, it does. The condition $A<B$ is in this context the same as condition $A=a_1$.

Answer (score 0):

I think $A<B$ happens exactly when $A = a_1$ for any value of $B$, so
$$
\mathbb{P}[A<B] = \mathbb{P}[A = a_1, B \in \{b_1, b_2\}] = 0.1 + 0.2 = 0.3
$$

Comment: Oops, oh yeah! So would that still hold true and we have $ca_1 * ((0.1)/(0.6) + (0.2)/(0.4))$?